# Появление верхнего меню в приложении

Tags: android, webview, меню

Есть простое приложение-обертка под Web с помощью webView. Проблема в том, что при отображении виртуальной клавиатуры появляется верхнее меню (то, что с часами и зарядом батареи) и не исчезает после свертывания клавиатуры. В интернете нашёл только съезжание всего окна, по моему вопросу - ничего.

Что я пробовал:

- Менял тему наподобии android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme"> везде, где возможно.
- Была эта же проблема при отображении диалога, но я решил ее, добавив в обработчик нажатия на кнопки диалога:

  `mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
      }
  };`

Это решило проблему только для диалоговых окон, но проблема осталась - после появления виртуальной клавиатуры верхнее меню никуда не исчезает.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

**activity_fullscreen**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context=".FullscreenActivity">

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:text="@string/dummy_content"
        android:textColor="#33b5e5"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/mywebview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:foregroundGravity="top">

    </WebView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
        style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>'
```

**AndroidManifext**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.crownalabugaru">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**FullScreenActivity**

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity   {
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private ShakeDetector mShakeDetector;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Выйти из приложения?")
                .setMessage("Нельзя выйти из приложения")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
    }    

    public void shaker() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Вы вошли в режим бога?")
                .setMessage("Вы круты")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                .create().show();
    }

//показ диалога при тряске
   public void showdialog() {
       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
// Add the buttons
       builder.setTitle("Вы вошли в режим бога");
       builder.setMessage("Вы круты");
       builder.setPositiveButton("Очистить кэш", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               // User clicked OK button
               //showdialog();
               WebView mywebview=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.mywebview);
               mywebview.clearCache(true);
               mywebview.clearHistory();
               //mywebview.reload();
               android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();
               mywebview.loadUrl("https://ya.ru");
               mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);    
           }
       });
       builder.setNegativeButton("Fix.php", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               // User cancelled the dialog
               WebView mywebview=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.mywebview);
                mywebview.loadUrl("https://mail.ya.ru/");
               getSupportActionBar().hide();
               mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);    
           }
       });
// Set other dialog properties    

// Create the AlertDialog
       AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
       dialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */
    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * Some older devices needs a small delay between UI widget updates
     * and a change of the status and navigation bar.
     */
    private static final int UI_ANIMATION_DELAY = 300;
    private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    private View mContentView;
    private final Runnable mHidePart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed removal of status and navigation bar

            // Note that some of these constants are new as of API 16 (Jelly Bean)
            // and API 19 (KitKat). It is safe to use them, as they are inlined
            // at compile-time and do nothing on earlier devices.
            mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        }
    };
    private View mControlsView;
    private final Runnable mShowPart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed display of UI elements
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.show();
            }
            mControlsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };
    private boolean mVisible;
    private final Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            hide();
        }
    };
    /**
     * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
     * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
     * while interacting with activity UI.
     */
    private final View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager
                .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mShakeDetector = new ShakeDetector();
        mShakeDetector.setOnShakeListener(new  ShakeDetector.OnShakeListener()       {

            @Override
            public void onShake(int count) {
                /*
                 * The following method, "handleShakeEvent(count):" is a stub //
                 * method you would use to setup whatever you want done once the
                 * device has been shook.
                 */

                showdialog();
            }
        });    

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

        mVisible = true;
        mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);


        // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
        mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggle();
            }
        });

WebView mywebview=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.mywebview);
        WebSettings websettings=mywebview.getSettings();
        websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Intent intent = null;

                String url2="https://ya.ru/";
                // all links  with in ur site will be open inside the webview
                //links that start ur domain example(http://www.example.com/)
                if (url != null && url.startsWith(url2)){
                    return false;
                }
                // all links that points outside the site will be open in a normal android browser
                else  {
                    view.getContext().startActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
        mywebview.loadUrl("https://ya.ru");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.
        delayedHide(100);
    }

    private void toggle() {
        if (mVisible) {
            hide();
        } else {
            show();
        }
    }

    private void hide() {
        // Hide UI first
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.hide();
        }
        mControlsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mVisible = false;

        // Schedule a runnable to remove the status and navigation bar after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mShowPart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHidePart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private void show() {
        // Show the system bar
        mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        mVisible = true;

        // Schedule a runnable to display UI elements after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHidePart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mShowPart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    /**
     * Schedules a call to hide() in delay milliseconds, canceling any
     * previously scheduled calls.
     */
    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Add the following line to register the Session Manager Listener onResume
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mShakeDetector, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        // Add the following line to unregister the Sensor Manager onPause
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mShakeDetector);
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону запрета отображения бара в манифесте

Comment: @Nik Уже пробовал, не помогло: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам. Сделал таймер, который каждую секунду меняет setSystemUiVisibility. Приложение вылетало, если открыта клавиатура, поэтому добавил проверку. Также была проблема с потоками, использовал хэндлеры, полное решение ниже. Всем спасибо.

```
 private Handler handler;
    private Runnable handlerTask;
    final Context context = this;
    void StartTimer(){
        handler = new Handler();
        handlerTask = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService
                        (Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                if (imm.isAcceptingText()) {
                    //        Log.d(TAG,"Software Keyboard was shown");
                } else {


                     mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                                    |   View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                                     | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                     |   View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    );

                }
```